# how to easy display limited number of items on the page and add link to more pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, sinatra

I am using sinatra and mustache for building application. I would like to display max 30 items on the page. I was thinking about will_paginate gem, but it seems to complicated. Is there any easier way to do it? this is my view for links.rb:

```
module S
  class App
    module Views
      class AdminLinks < Layout

        def links_all
          Links.all.map do |s|
            {
              :name => s.name,
              :comments_num => s.comments.count,
              :user_name => s.user ? s.user.name : "" ,
              :created_at => s.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db) ,
              :user_id => s.user ? s.user.id : "" ,
              :streme_id => s.id,
            }
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am wondering how to use: Links.limit(5).offset(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bare bone pagination you can use

```
# in controller
@page = params[:page] ? 1 : params[:page].to_i


# in model
def links_all(page)
      per_page = 30
      Links.limit(per_page).offset( (page - 1) * per_page ).all.map do |s|
        {
          :name => s.name,
          :comments_num => s.comments.count,
          :user_name => s.user ? s.user.name : "" ,
          :created_at => s.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db) ,
          :user_id => s.user ? s.user.id : "" ,
          :streme_id => s.id,
        }
      end
end

# in view (replace links_path with your path helper
<%= link_to "Previous Page", links_path(:page => @page - 1 ) if @page > 1 %>
<%= link_to "Next Page", links_path(:page => @page + 1 ) %>
```